# How to use Kotlin async and await for factorials?

Tags: android, asynchronous, kotlin

I have this function in Kotlin (Android app):

```
tailrec fun factorial(n: BigInteger, remainder: BigInteger = BigInteger.ONE) : BigInteger{
    if(n== BigInteger.ZERO)
        return remainder
    else {
        return factorial(n - BigInteger.ONE, remainder * n)
    }
}
```

and this simple code:

```
button.setOnClickListener {
        val n = editTextT.text.toString()
        val result: BigInteger = factorial(BigInteger(n))
        textView.text = "$n! is $result"
    }
```

My question is: Is there a way to do this kind of computation in an asynchronous way? If yes, how?

Comment: Do you want each recursive call of `factorial` to run asynchronously (for experimentation), or only run the whole computation in a coroutine off the UI thread?

Comment: off the UI thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Anko support for coroutines (described in [this article](https://android.jlelse.eu/a-first-walk-into-kotlin-coroutines-on-android-fe4a6e25f46a)) you can run a coroutine that performs the code in the UI thread but run and await actions in background, in your case it would look like:

```
button.setOnClickListener {
    val n = editTextT.text.toString()
    async(UI) {
        val result: Deferred<BigInteger> = bg { factorial(BigInteger(n)) }
        textView.text = "$n! is ${result.await()}"
    }
}
```

See also: [Anko reference](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/wiki/Anko-Coroutines)

Comment: Updated the answer and fixed the mistake with `.await()` missing.

Comment: After adding compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-coroutines:$anko_version" it says Failed to resolve org.jetbrains.anko:anko-coroutines:0.9.0. What should I do?

Comment: @AndreiPaciurca Please check that you have `jcenter()` in your project's `repositories { ... }`(or in `allprojects { ... }` / `subprojects { ... }`). Also, the latest Anko version is now 0.10.2.

Comment: It works! 
Shouldn't be val result: Deferred<BigInteger> = bg { factorial(BigInteger(n)) } ?

Comment: @AndreiPaciurca, indeed, `Deferred<BigInteger>` is the right type, fixed.